# setResult in Android activity and receive in grand parent activity when parent activity is finished before child activity

Tags: android, kotlin, startactivityforresult

I have a scenario where

Activity A --> A start Activity B for result -> B start activity C for result and B is finished --> Activity C finished with a result -> Activity A should receive the result from C.

I think as activity B finish before activity c, Activity A is not receiving the result.

Is there any way we can get the result in this scenario where parent is closed before child and result should be in grand parent

Thank You

Comment: if  B start activity C for result i think B will not finished before C give B the result

Comment: @op just keep middle `Activity` still alive (don't `finish`) and when you leave C and B gets result then immediatelly close also B and return result to A

Comment: It means you need to finish ActivityB when startActivityForResult to C returns a result

Answer (score 0):

Normally an activity will not be removed from back stack if you don't instruct to do so. If that happens, you will not get any result. In that case, you can use callbacks, but it's not a clean way of designing your application. You have to check many things before implementing such thing, so that the app don't crush.

Answer (score 0):

According to your schenario Please Try to set result with OK from C and then check that result in onActivityResult of B, and from B onActivityResult again set result with OK and finish the activity B, now you can get the result in A  onActivityResult method, but between this process please do not close the activity B before get result.

Another Way but not recommend so you can achieve this by static variable in C with check validation in onstart method of A activity and null variable after use.

Hope above idea will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ResultContract that takes you from activity A to activityB, and then another one that takes you from ActivityB to activityC.

Once you have done that, you can then set your result in ActivityC.
When ActivityB receives it, you have to set that same result so that ActivityA can get it

ActivityA: 
`private val aActivityRL= registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->` 
    `if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {result.data}`
}`

`aActivityRL.launchIntent(Intent(this,ActivityB::class.java))`

ActivityB: 
`private val bActivityRL= registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->` 
    `if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result.data)}` 
`}`

`bActivityRL.launchIntent(Intent(this,ActiviyC::class.java))`

ActivityC: 
`setResult(Activity.Result_OK, yourIntentResult)`